# node gulp ionic install error

Tags: node.js, command-line, gulp, ionic-framework

I am getting the following error when trying to install ionic:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.13.0-pre
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.18
npm ERR! code ENOTSUP

npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: gulp@3.8.8
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":">= 0.9"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"2.1.18","node":"0.13.0-pre"}

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/taylorsuk/npm-debug.log
```

Details of the npm-debug.log are below:

```
29053 verbose unlock done using /Users/taylorsuk/.npm/_locks/cordova-f29da3a706471ecd.lock for /Users/taylorsuk/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/cordova
29054 verbose stack Error: Unsupported
29054 verbose stack     at checkEngine (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-install-checks/index.js:16:16)
29054 verbose stack     at Array.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/bind-actor.js:15:8)
29054 verbose stack     at LOOP (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:15:14)
29054 verbose stack     at chain (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:20:5)
29054 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:949:5
29054 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/locker.js:40:9
29054 verbose stack     at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/lockfile/lockfile.js:149:38)
29054 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/lockfile/lockfile.js:171:16
29054 verbose stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:93:15)
29055 verbose pkgid gulp@3.8.8
29056 verbose cwd /Users/taylorsuk
29057 error Darwin 14.0.0
29058 error argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
29059 error node v0.13.0-pre
29060 error npm  v2.1.18
29061 error code ENOTSUP
29062 error notsup Unsupported
29062 error notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: gulp@3.8.8
29062 error notsup Required: {"node":">= 0.9"}
29062 error notsup Actual:   {"npm":"2.1.18","node":"0.13.0-pre"}
29063 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
29064 verbose unbuild lib/node_modules/ionic
29065 info preuninstall ionic@1.3.2
29066 info uninstall ionic@1.3.2
29067 verbose unbuild rmStuff ionic@1.3.2 from /Users/taylorsuk/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules
29068 verbose gentlyRm verifying that /Users/taylorsuk/.npm-packages is managed by npm
29069 silly isManaged /Users/taylorsuk/.npm-packages is not inside /Users/taylorsuk/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules
29070 silly isManaged /Users/taylorsuk/.npm-packages is not inside /Users/taylorsuk/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules
29071 silly isManaged /Users/taylorsuk/.npm-packages is not inside /Users/taylorsuk/.npm-packages/bin
29072 silly isManaged /Users/taylorsuk/.npm-packages is inside /Users/taylorsuk/.npm-packages
29073 silly gentlyRm /Users/taylorsuk/.npm-packages is managed by npm
29074 silly gentlyRm /Users/taylorsuk/.npm-packages/bin/ionic is under /Users/taylorsuk/.npm-packages
29075 verbose gentlyRm vacuuming /Users/taylorsuk/.npm-packages/bin/ionic up to /Users/taylorsuk/.npm-packages
29076 info postuninstall ionic@1.3.2
29077 verbose gentlyRm vacuuming /Users/taylorsuk/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ionic
29078 silly gentlyRm purging /Users/taylorsuk/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/ionic
29079 silly gentlyRm quitting because other entries in /Users/taylorsuk/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules`
```

I have been having issues with installing node_modules in a user directory rather than having to use `sudo` which I have solved by adding the path to `.bash_profile` however I cannot get ionic installed again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

Completely node by following these [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x):

Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

Run `brew doctor`
remove all symbolic links etc using `brew prune`
Run `brew install node`

Then run `npm install -g cordova ionic`

Additional steps I included was delete `/Users/username/.bash_profile` as I had messed up some symbolic linking.